# Exception while extend DroidGap

Tags: android

I done few phone gap projects before, This time a new exception raised in my code . 
In my new project i include phonegap jar(cordova 1.5)  and in the manifest i declared  droidgap class(tried with both com.hb.DroidGap and org.apache.cordova.DroidGap).
now if i extend to Activity the debugger entering to onCreate method but if i extend to DroidGap
the below exception is coming and app geting force close (Debugger in not coming to onCreate) ... 
Is there any thing i am missing ?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English

```
  06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hiddenbrains/com.hiddenbrains.HBPluginsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hiddenbrains.HBPluginsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.hiddenbrains-1.apk]
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hiddenbrains.HBPluginsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.hiddenbrains-1.apk]
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
    06-07 10:03:54.954: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this exact problem too. Everything was working until a specific time last night, then I started getting these errors. App crashes every time. I have traced the problem to the .java file in src>MyApp.name... if I remove the cordova line, eg. class MyApp extends DroidGap and set it to the default the app doesn't crash, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Turns out it was crashing due to 1) problems in a javascript file and 2) an incorrect manifest. I corrected by isolating the javascript file and finding the errors, and then by rewriting the manifest file from the beginning using the guide from phonegap